# Send ctrl + z to Cisco device

Tags: tcl, expect, cisco, ctrl

I have a need to send <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> to a Cisco device via TCL and Expect Scripting in order to get a prompt so that the scripting can perform an operation on the device.  An example would be that if the script finds the state to be:

```
--MORE--
```

If you are sitting at the console you can send <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and you will get:

```
#:
```

How can I do this from an automated script.  I have tried:

```
send "\u001A";
```

and

```
send "\x1A";
```

They seem to be ignored.

Comment: What platform are you on?

Comment: The script is running on a Linux box. I am not sure how the platform applies.  I am sending the command to a Cisco device. So whether the script is running on Windows or Linux server wouldn't the command be the same?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should be able to find exactly what octal value your <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> has by using od (octal dump), and then sticking that in your script.

See a good explanation on how to determine that here:

http://expect.sourceforge.net/FAQ.html#q54

Other than that, I have to say that Vidiyal's suggestion (trying with <kbd>Q</kbd> instead of <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>) has merit, and is a lot simpler.

Answer (score 0):

--MORE--  in the cisco ios can also be get rid and return to the device prompt , if you send "q"
try  it out manually on device  and just send "q" to return to prompt..Hope it solves issue...